# Convert Array of objects to array of integers

Tags: laravel-5

I need to convert the following array of objects to array of integers in laravel. Below is the code which I need to convert as an array.

```
  $idArray = DB::table('booking_header')
        ->select('booking_header.id')
        ->where('booking_header.parent_booking_id', $oldId)
        ->get();
```

I tried with pluck(). But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pluck() insted of get() to get a simple array of ids.

```
$idArray = DB::table('booking_header')
    ->select('booking_header.id')
    ->where('booking_header.parent_booking_id', $oldId)->pluck('booking_header.id');
```

Comment: Call to a member function all() on array error will come for that

Comment: I see, pluck() in laravel 5.2 returns simple array (not collection). In this case you don't need use all()

Comment: I've tested pluck() - works fine like I mention. In other case something wrong in your query. Make sure, that your where condition is correct.